# Changing idle timeout of AWS Load Balancer doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-load-balancer-controller

I have backend in Spring boot and front end in react js which is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

When calling backend API which takes more than one minute to process the request, I see gateway timeout error on browser console.
I saw load balancer is configured with default idle timeout value of 60sec. I changed it to 240seconds but still I get gateway timeout at exactly 60sec. What can be the root cause now? Why AWS attribute change doesn't reflect.

Comment: This isnt really a programming question. You might have more luck on ServerFault. I would suggest you look at the logs from your load balencer and application server - both will have a timeout.